# Intuition of partial derivative equations. (Faraday's Law - Maxwell's 3rd equation)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

## Context

I am struggling to get an intuition about Maxwell's equations. I created this silly mental model. I want to know if it is incorrect. How do other people think about these equations in their minds eye?

Assumptions:

- I have an Electric test charge which I can move in the $x$ direction, the $y$ direction or the $z$ direction.
- I measure the Electric force on the Electric test charge in the $x$ direction and call this $\boldsymbol E_{x}$
- I measure the Electric force on the Electric test charge in the $y$ direction and call this $\boldsymbol E_{y}$
- I measure the Electric force on the Electric test charge in the $z$ direction and call this $\boldsymbol E_{z}$

### [image]

- I have a Magnetic monopole test charge which I can move in the $x$ direction, the $y$ direction or the $z$ direction.
- I measure the force on my monopole in the $x$ direction and call it $\boldsymbol B_{x}$
- I measure the force on my monopole in the $y$ direction and call it $\boldsymbol B_{y}$
- I measure the force on my monopole in the $z$ direction and call it $\boldsymbol B_{z}$

---

Using my assumptions I go on to build a heuristic understanding of these 3 Maxwell equations:

$$\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E_{z}}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E_{y}}{\partial z}= - \frac{\partial \boldsymbol B_{x}}{\partial t}$$

$$\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E_{x}}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E_{z}}{\partial x}= - \frac{\partial \boldsymbol B_{y}}{\partial t}$$

$$\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E_{y}}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E_{x}}{\partial y}= - \frac{\partial \boldsymbol B_{z}}{\partial t}$$

---

## Question

#### Is this heuristic understanding correct? If it is not or if you have a better understanding please tell me it?

> $$\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E_{z}}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E_{y}}{\partial z}= - \frac{\partial \boldsymbol B_{x}}{\partial t}$$

this first equation can be understood as:

> - I nudge my Electric test charge in the $y$ direction and I record a corresponding change in Electric force in the $z$ direction (change in $\boldsymbol E_{z}$). How sensitive is the force on my charge is to a nudge in the $y$ direction.
> - $\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E_{z}}{\partial y}$ is the ratio of: change in $\boldsymbol E_{z}$ per 1 unit of displacement in the $y$ direction.
> - $\frac{\partial \boldsymbol E_{y}}{\partial z}$ I nudge my Electric test charge in the $z$ direction and I record a corresponding change in force in the y direction ($\partial \boldsymbol E_{y}$). I calculate a new ratio of: change in force per 1 unit of displacement.
> - I notice that all these movements and measurements are mysteriously perpendicular to each other.
> - I take the difference of these ratios and this tells me the change in  force on my magnetic test charge as I nudge the magnetic test charge through time. (Alternatively) the force on my magnetic test charge in the x direction $\boldsymbol B_{x}$ changes through time. $\frac{\partial \boldsymbol B_{x}}{\partial t}$

Comment: Most likely the integral forms of Maxwell's equations will be easier for you to understand, because there is some "integration by parts" involved in converting them to the differential form, which strips away some of the physical intuition. For example, the equation you're looking at is Faraday's law of induction, which says "The voltage accumulated around a closed circuit is proportional to the time rate of change of the magnetic flux it encloses." (Wikipedia).

Comment: I will read that now. cheers.